# What's with the default user icons?

Tags: discussion, profile-picture, gravatar

In my time of programming things, I have had many questions, and have gone to many Q&A sites for answers.  One thing I noticed about many of these Q&A websites have something in common: the default user icons.

[image: Stack Overflow]]

[image: MSDN]]

[image: Unreal Engine Q&A]

(from Stack Overflow, MSDN [sorry for the image scaling], and UE4 Answer Hub respectively)  So why do all of these websites, and more, have this style of default icon?  Is it just something completely random?  It just pops out to me for some reason.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/gravatar/info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While these icons are somewhat related to Gravatar, they're actually [Identicons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon).

As you can read on the linked Wikipedia article, identicons are generated icons based on a hash of something (email address, username, IP address, +/- date of creation of account), and are widespread. Many websites use Gravatar with an Identicon as fallback, while Stack Exchange allows you to pick either an Identicon, your gravatar image, or an image you uploaded.

You can change these settings by going to your profile page, and choosing edit profile & settings.